# Store a struct in a file using fwrite

Tags: c, file, pointers, struct

I would like to store a struct in a file. 
I used this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    short b;
    char *ch;
} wrFile;

main()
{
    FILE* fd=fopen("Result.txt","w+");
    wrFile wf={12451,14,"result"};
    fwrite(&wf,sizeof(wrFile),1,fd);
    fclose(fd);
}
```

the resul that I obtained in Result.txt is:

```
£0^@^@^N^@^@^@^Z^G@^@^@^@^@^@
```

The question is why?

Comment: A `struct` is a binary construct, so writing it to a file won't automatically format it in a readable way.

Comment: Explain how you "obtain" the result. If you just open it with text editor, you won't get a readable result. You need to handle the format of text yourself.

Answer (score 8):

w+ would be correct on linux, w+b is only needed on windows. But i guess the OP wanted to see something like `"12451, 14,` result" in the file and is confused why he doesn't.

`fwrite()` writes data directly in binary form, intended to be read by `fread()` later, not intended to be readable by humans.

Your `12451`, as a 4 byte integer, in hex, is `00 00 30 a3`. As intel processors store data in little endian format, it would be written to the file as `a3 30 00 00`. Which is exactly what we see - your first 4 characters are the pound sign, which has a hex code of A3, the next is the 0, (`30` in hex), then 2 zero bytes. Same with the 14.

As your ch is a pointer, the pointer is written, not the string ("result") it points to.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a misunderstanding of what fwrite actually does.
After writing your struct to the file, you can't expect to read it back using a text editor. If you wanted that, you would have to use

```
fprintf(fd, "%i, %i, %s\n", wf.a, wf.b, wf.ch);
```

because fwrite will write the struct to file to be machine readable, that is in its most compact binary form, which your text editor does not understand.

Also, if you frwite a char* to a file, you just write the pointer, and not the contents.

Comment: I used this code to understand what fwrite does. I think that the advantage of fwrite is that it can write "compund types" like structure and array in a file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`FILE* fd=fopen("Result.txt","w+");`

Use

`FILE* fd=fopen("Result.txt","wb+");`

to specify binary file mode.

The first way specifies the text mode, so everything you write is read as (usually) 1 byte `char`, while what you really want to write is a **binary data** (stream of bytes arranged in some blocks). Also you can change the extension from `.txt` to some other so not to get confused with text file.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `fwrite(&wf,sizeof(wrFile),1,fd);`, what you are writing is the actual bytes in memory to the file. In other words, you're writing the 'raw' data into the file instead of the textual representation.

Consider using [`fprintf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/printf.html) instead like such

```
fprintf(&wf, "a=%d\n", wf.a);
fprintf(&wf, "b=%d\n", wf.b);
fprintf(&wf, "ch=%s\n", wf.ch);
```

Given your code above, this would output the following to the file pointed to by `wf`:

```
a=12451
b=14
ch=result
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are using normal `fwrite` function which doesn't format the input. If you want to see proper data in the `*.txt` file, use `fprintf`. 
Also, `wrFile` will be padded with some extra bytes for alignment purpose which will also be written into file if you use `fwrite` function.

Instead use

```
fprintf(fd, "%d, %d, %s", wf.a, wf.b, wf.ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

That you're naming your output file `Result.txt` suggests you expected human-readable ASCII text output.

That's not what `fwrite` will give you if you hand it a buffer of binary data (your struct).  In your case, you should open with `wb+` to ensure your struct memory is correctly written.  Also, I suggest not naming the file with a `.txt` extension -- it is not incorrect, but it is sure to cause confusion with humans.

A good way to convince yourself that you're getting the right output is to `fread` your data back into a struct and compare to the original.  That would be a useful exercise for you.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get unexpected file output is because you write the structures into the file by their bit pattern.

A lot of problems in this case:

1. the `int`-typed field `a` is written into file in binary mode;
2. there is a `short`-typed field `b`, and if your machine is 32-bit or 64-bit, there will be padding bits which are of course un-predictable (or un-printable);
3. you have a `char*`-typed field `ch` which is a pointer, or say it is a memory address and is only valid in this run of the program (if you run your program again, there could be other data occupying this chunk of memory).

So IMHO, you should change your code like this:

```
fprintf(fd, "%d %hd %s\n", wf.a, wf.b, wf.ch);
```

And next time you read from the file, you should parse the data yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others you could use `fprintf`, but if you wish to stick to `fwrite`, you could store the values in a buffer, then write to file:

```
    char cBuffer[1024]="";
...
snprintf(cBuffer, sizeof(cBuffer),"%d %hd %s",wf.a,wf.b,wf.ch);
fwrite(cBuffer,strlen(cBuffer),1,fd);
```

And don't forget to check if `fd==NULL` after using `fopen`